# plot chart with multi lines and group by column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, charts

I have a dataframe from a csv file where I have 3 columns "Date", "value" and "Case". I want to be able to plot the data as a line chart where there are different cases and each case should have its own line [like this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/_images/frame_plot_basic.png). So these cases is many and I was thinking there must be some function to "group" these cases and display them in different lines with different colors. I want in my chart to have Date as x axis and value as y axis. How can I achieve this?

here is my code: (I am a beginner so my code may be seen bad)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_csvfile():
    df = pd.read_csv('ebola_data_db_format.csv', sep= ',')
    
    #remove the unneeded columns
    df = df[df['Country'] != "Guinea 2"]  
    df = df[df['Country'] != "Liberia 2"]
   
    #reset the index
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    
    #group by country, now for every element v have a different country
    for k, v in df.groupby('Country'):
        
        #here I try to group by case and plot but it does not work
        fig,ax = v.subplots()
        for a,b in df.groupby('Case'):
            b.plot(x='Date',y='value', ax=ax)

        #v.to_csv(f'{k}.csv')

read_csvfile()
```

Comment: `fig,ax = v.subplots()` should be `fig,ax = plt.subplots()`. For the inside loop, use `for a,b in v.groupby('Case')`.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Date', y='value', hue='Case')
```

If you wouldn't, pandas can do:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for k,v in df.groupby('Case'):
    v.plot(x='Date',y='value', ax=ax)
```

Comment: check updated question. I posted my code but it does not really work yet